# TinyMCE, add css style on elements in a listbox (toolbar)

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

I'm creating a new plugin, a listbox on toolbar.

This listbox allows you to change size of the selected text.

Here my code for add a listbox on my editor toolbar :

```
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.ListBoxPlugin', {
    createControl: function(n, cm) {
        switch (n) {
            case 'listeStyle':
                var mlb = cm.createListBox('listeStyle', {
                    title : 'Styles',
                    onselect : function(v) {                        
                        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceReplaceContent',false,'<span class='+v+'>{$selection}</span>');
                     }
                });

               <?php               
               foreach($matches[1] as $m){
                    echo "mlb.add('".$m."', '".$m."');";
               }
               ?>               
                return mlb;
        }
        return null;
    }
});
tinymce.PluginManager.add('listBox', tinymce.plugins.ListBoxPlugin);
```

So, for add elements on my listbox, it's with this line :

```
echo mlb.add('".$m."', '".$m."');
```

For example, with `mlb.add('medium', '15');`, i i have an element on my listbox named "medium" and when i click, i retrieve the value "15".

So, how can i do, using tinymce i guess, for display element in this listbox with css ? For example, for this element, i need to display him with the size "15".

What i need : [image]

What i have : [image]

Do you understand ? Thanks :)

Edit : I create this listbox dynamically

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, this is a difficult task.
Easiest way seems to apply custom styles on the tinymce event init.
The browser is then ready.

**Update**: This should give you something to build your listbox upon.
You will need to tweak `sizes` and `description` (dynamically) to your needs:

```
if (mlb) {
    var i =0 ;
    var sizes = [{ fontSize:"5"},{ fontSize:"10"},{ fontSize:"20"}];
    var description = ['Text1','Text2','Text3'];
    each(sizes, function(v, k) {
       var size = v.fontSize;

       if (size >= 1 && size <= 7)
           size = t.sizes[parseInt(size) - 1] + 'pt';

       c.add(y[i], v, {'style' : 'font-size:' + size});
       i++;
    });
}
return mlb;
```

Comment: Yes, but i can't know all size (for my example). I'm using my cms, and lots of users can add or remove element on thi list box...

Comment: Hum, yeah, why not ! ^^ And add a class , it's possible ? {'class' : 'fontSize'} for example doesn't work.

Comment: this should be possible: c.add(y[i], v, {'style' : 'font-size:' + size, 'class' : 'fontSize'});